# I can't figure out why I get this: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

So I get this error when I try to use my code.

```
File "/Users/max/Desktop/Code/Python/game.py", line 30, in <module>
        lineone.remove[0]       #or whatever number I use
    TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

My code is

```
lineone = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
linetwo = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
linethree = ['0', '0', '0']
lineoneX = ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
linetwoX = ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
linethreeX = ['X', 'X', 'X']
notfirst = 0
player1 = input('''Enter player 1's name ''')
player2 = input('''Enter player 2's name ''')
print('The person who takes the last stone wins!')
print(lineone[0], lineone[1], lineone[2], lineone[3], lineone[4], lineone[5], lineone[6])
print(linetwo[0], linetwo[1], linetwo[2], linetwo[3], linetwo[4])
print(linethree[0], linethree[1], linethree[2])

while True:
    #WTD means -What to Delete
    WTD = input('Type the row number, then the amount of stones you want to take, in the format 1, 1. ')
          # Line One
    if WTD == '1, 1':
          lineone.remove[0]
    if WTD == '1, 2':
          lineone.remove[1]
    if WTD == '1, 3':
          lineone.remove[2]
    if WTD == '1, 4':
          lineone.remove[3]
    if WTD == '1, 5':
          lineone.remove[4]
    if WTD == '1, 6':
          lineone.remove[5]
    if WTD == '1, 7':
          lineone.remove[6]
          # Line Two
    if WTD == '2, 1':
          linetwo.remove[0]
    if WTD == '2, 2':
          linetwo.remove[1]
    if WTD == '2, 3':
          linetwo.remove[2]
    if WTD == '2, 4':
          linetwo.remove[3]
    if WTD == '2, 5':
          linetwo.remove[4]
          # Line Three
    if WTD == '3, 1':
          linetwo.remove[0]
    if WTD == '3, 2':
          linetwo.remove[1]
    if WTD == '2, 3':
          linetwo.remove[2]
    print(lineone)
    print(linetwo)
    print(linethree)
```

I' ve looked in a lot of other places but I can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm using square brackets, I'm using 0 and not 1 for the first item. 
So please help,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `remove` is a method; you call it with parentheses, not brackets. It also doesn't do what you're trying to do, so you're still going to have problems after you change the brackets.

Comment: What do you mean by:   It also doesn't do what you're trying to do

Comment: You're trying to remove a specified number of items from the list. `remove` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use *remove* like a list or dictionary while it's a function and that's why you get `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`. Instead, you should try `lineone.remove('0')` if you want to remove first '0' element, or for e.g. `lineone.pop(0)` if you want to remove first element. Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html) for details.